# Can I alias the dot sourcing command?

Tags: powershell

I find myself missing the . in dot sourced files and spending a little time getting my footing when switching from C# to PS. Is there a way to alias the . or use a similar command that is more blatantly noticeable?

Comment: I guess you could technically use `Import-Module` depending on the file contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: **No**, you cannot define an alias for `.` :

`.`, the [(dot-)sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), is an *operator* and as such it cannot be the target of an *alias* (only *commands* can).

Defining a *function* is also not an option, because it would itself have to be dot-sourced when called, in order to be able to dot-source other commands (scripts whose definitions to load into the *caller's* scope).